# Pandas Datetime Object Differencing - Timedelta Bug?

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something or if this is a bug.

```
In [78]: df['time'][0]
Out[78]: Timestamp('2009-04-19 13:09:35')

In [79]: df['time'][1]
Out[79]: Timestamp('2009-04-19 13:09:39')

In [80]: (df['time'][0]-df['time'][1])
Out[80]: Timedelta('-1 days +23:59:56')

In [81]: (df['time'][0]-df['time'][1]).seconds
Out[81]: 86396
```

I thought the seconds attribute on the timedelta object would return -4 but instead it's returned 86396 (i.e. 86400 - 4).

Is this a bug or have I misunderstood what the seconds attribute should be doing?

Comment: I think need [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html), for Series - [`dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html)

Comment: Yep, that resolved it. Thanks. I still don't understand what seconds is doing though.